# Custom draw navigation not rendering - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to replace default drawer navigator with customDrawerNavigator. I have used ScrollView, DrawerNavigatorItems and passed props inside the custom drawer component. I have an AppNavigator component which renders the drawer navigator.

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator, ScrollView,DrawerNavigatorItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {Icon, Body, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
import {Image, View} from 'react-native';
import Admin from '../screens/Admin.js';
import Manager from '../screens/Manager.js';
import Login from '../screens/Login.js'

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    Admin: {
        screen: Admin
    },
    Manager: {
        screen: Manager
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Admin',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
);

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

    <Container>
      <Header style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 50}}>
        <Body>
          <Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={require("../assets/logo.png")}/>
          <ScrollView>
            <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
            <Text>Your Own Footer Area After</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </Body>
     </Header>
   </Container>
  ); 

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

I have an AppNavigator content to wrap this DrawerNavigator and rendered inside the App.js file.

```
export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        // Auth: Login,
        Main:DrawerNavigator,
    })
);
```

But I'm getting an empty drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Navigators need to be wrapped inside createAppContainer provided by react-navigation :

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    Admin: {
        screen: Admin
    },
    Manager: {
        screen: Manager
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Admin',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
);

const Container = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
export default Container;
```

Hope, this will help.

Comment: I have tried using the above method. But I'm getting an empty drawer. In fact, I have a AppNavigator component in which I wrapped DrawerNavigator and rendered the same in App.js

Comment: export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        // Auth: Login,
        Main:DrawerNavigator,
    })
);

Comment: Actually I'm not getting any error. Just the drawer is blank when I'm using the CustomDrawerComponent as the contentComponent

Comment: check props for CustomDrawerContentComponent , Are you getting route names in props?

Comment: I have tried like this <DrawerItems {...props.Admin} />. But still not working. How do I check it's properly?

Comment: console.log(props)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209081/discussion-between-musthafa-and-deepankar-singh).